# DynamoDB Session Handler Site Wide Used with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to launch a LAMP environment. Due to Elastic Beanstalk being an multiple instance environment, `$_SESSION` is not configured to work correctly and it is recommended to use [DynamoDB Session Handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html). This works fine for me with the following code inserted prior to session_start();

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Session\SessionHandler;

$dynamoDb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'XXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXX',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
));

$sessionHandler = SessionHandler::factory(array(
    'dynamodb_client' => $dynamoDb,
    'table_name'      => 'sessions',
));
$sessionHandler->register();
```

But, this does not work app wide and is causing issues getting phpMyAdmin up and running. How do I make this work app wide?

Comment: Could you explain more specifically what you mean by "app-wide"?

Comment: Anywhere I could place this without placing it directly into the phpMyAdmin or other 3rd party code. I did get phpMyAdmin working by adding this code to /libraries/common.inc.php of phpMyAdmin but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to configure a custom session handler from a php.ini, and to use the DynamoDB Session Handler, you must bootstrap it somehow. For an app with multiple entry points, this presents a challenge. One idea you could try is using the [`auto_prepend_file` INI setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) to run the bootstrap code.